# Mapping from ViewModel to DTo to Domain using automapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I'm having a trouble do the following mapping:

Domain (simplified version):

```
public class Ad
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Kms { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class CreateAdDto
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Kms { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual ModelDto Model { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class CreateAdViewModel
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Kms { get; set; }

    public int Make_Id { get; set; }
    public int Model_Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MakeList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ModelList { get; set; }
}
```

In the Controller, when I do the Mapping I'm loosing the Make_ID from the Dropdownlist of the View:

```
    public virtual ActionResult Create(CreateAdViewModel adViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var adDto = Mapper.Map<CreateAdViewModel, CreateAdDto>(adViewModel);

            _adService.CreateAd(adDto);
        }

        return RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.Index());
    }
```

The mapping is:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<CreateAdViewModel, CreateAdDto>()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentionned, the Ad need to know the Model_Id and to set it into the Model

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CreateAdDto, Ad>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Model, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Model { Id = src.Model_Id }));
```

You also need from the other mapping side to let the Dto know where to get the Model id.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Ad, CreateAdDto>()
         .ForMember(dest => dest.Model_Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Model.Id}));
```

The code above is not secure because a validation to see if Model is null should be added.

For the rest of your code, you seem to do it right. The section with Entity Framework requires you to attach because the entity Model already exist, otherwise, EF would insert this entity to the database.

Answer (score 0):

CreateAdDto doesn't have a Make navigation property or a Make_Id property.

Comment: The problem is with Model_Id that get lost from Dto to Domain. I can't find a way to map Model_Id to Model navigation property inside the Ad Domain entity

Answer (score 0):

Solution found after some research:

ViewDomain:

```
public class CreateAdViewModel
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Kms { get; set; }

    public int Make_Id { get; set; }
    public int Model_Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MakeList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ModelList { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class CreateAdDto
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Kms { get; set; }
    public int Model_Id { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    //public virtual ModelDto Model { get; set; }
}
```

Domain:

```
public class Ad
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Kms { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

Viewmodel -> Dto Mapping:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<CreateAdViewModel, CreateAdDto>();
```

Dto -> Domain Mapping:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<CreateAdDto, Ad>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.Model, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Model { Id = src.Model_Id }));
```

Atention:

To achieve this with Entity Framework, I had to attach first the Model Entity to the Context and then Ad the new Ad:

```
    public void CreateAd(CreateAdDto adDto)
    {
        var adDomain = Mapper.Map<CreateAdDto, Ad>(adDto);

        _modelRepository.Attach(adDomain.Model);

        _adRepository.Add(adDomain);
        _adRepository.Save();
    }
```

Hope this is the best practice.

BTW I would like to have some opinions regarding this aproach.

Thanks.

Comment: What is scale of your application?

Comment: @Arash it's planned to be a large application (like 40 SQL tables just to get the idea)

Comment: That's fine. I write an approach as soon as possible in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is I see in your question, I suggest a simple approach. Your application is medium scale. You should very carefully about **maintainability**,my experience say.So try to create a simple an strain forward approach for yourself like below approach:
[image: Application Architecture]

I can describe all layer in detail but with notice to title of your question I prefer describe only Model(bussiness Ojbect) layer:

[image: Model or Business Object layer]

Good! As you can see PM.Model include:
Tow sub folders contain our ViewModels and in root of Library we have a .tt file contain Entity framework Objects (POCO classes) and we have a Mapper folder(Since that i dont like use autoMapper or third party like this :) ).

You can see IListBox interface in Domain layer. I put all ListBox container to this interface.

I hope current approach useful for you but **finally** I suggest remove one of this layers DTO or ViewModel, because in the future will be very complex.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! Has I can see, your Business (Model) Layer works directly over the Domain Objects and delivers Domain data, but if you need to encapsulate data from more than one Entity in the Business layer and send it to the UI, how can you achieve this without DTO OBjects?

Comment: Yes, in the business layer ViewModels map to Entity framework Objects and use for CRUD oprations.I have not any DTO! I have Entity framework Objects (POCO) and ViewModel objects (Using for binding our views)

Answer (score -2):

Do you aware about cost of these mapping?! You have 2 layers mapping (before arrived to Entity framework) for an simple insert.We can do more complex CRUD(s) in less than 2 layers mapping.
How to think about maintainability of this code?

Please keep DRY,KISS,SOLID conventions in your mind and top of your everyday work.

Good luck

Comment: Hi, I think it's the best way to have very distinct layers, each one with his responsability, and passing the data using his channel from domain to view passing by service layer. If I make some exceptions of not using DTO in some ocasions I'm risking to not be consistent and introducing more complexity in the project.